# Need assist why this yaml is failing

Tags: yaml

The error appears to be in '/home/labdude/vagansible/k8ioTest1/kubernetes-setup/master-playbook.yml': line 71, column 12, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
when: ansible_swaptotal_mb > 0
 - name: Add an apt signing key for Kubernetes
       ^ here
```

Comment: Have you tried using online yaml linters? http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I tried.

Comment: @LearningNoob You should not recommend yamllint.com, it is know to have parsing problems.

Answer (score 0):

They mapping key `when` has a plain (i.e. non-quoted) scalar as argument. Such a scalar can be multi-line, but has a few restriction including that it cannot include a mapping indicator followed by space (`:` ). So either use:

```
when: "ansible_swaptotal_mb > 0
 - name: Add an apt signing key for Kubernetes"
```

or get rid of the space after `:`

```
when: ansible_swaptotal_mb > 0
 - name:Add an apt signing key for Kubernetes
```

or adjust the indentation of the line starting with `- name` if that is supposed to be a sequence item consisting of a mapping entry (dedent with several positions matching other sequence items).